# Do these very VERY weak axioms guarantee a group? (Every element has left identity $e_L$ or right identity $e_R$, with same-sided inverse)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, axioms, semigroups

I can't help but ask, after we've come so far weakening the group axioms in [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4249549/do-these-ultraweak-one-sided-group-axioms-guarantee-a-group) two [posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4252780/do-these-very-weak-axioms-define-a-group-every-element-has-left-identity-lef), whether we can get *even* weaker?

Let $A$ be a set with an associative binary operation $*$, and suppose there exist two elements $e_L,e_R\in A$ such that, for all $x\in A$, at least one of the following two conditions holds:

1. $e_L*x=x$ and there exists an $x'\in A$ such that $x'*x=e_L$;
2. $x*e_R=x$ and there exists an $x'\in A$ such that $x*x'=e_R$.

**Must $(A,*)$ be a group?**

The second linked post proves that the answer is “yes” in the case where $e_L=e_R$. This generalized version was posed by @Yakk in the comments to @Vincent's answer in the first linked post.

Comment: If both conditions hold, then $e_R = e_L * e_R = e_L$

Comment: @AlvinL Yes, but only if both conditions hold. Otherwise we do not know that $e_L$ is a left inverse for $e_R$ and vice versa.

Comment: In general we might only have $e_L*e_L=e_L$ and $e_R*e_R=e_R$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take $A = \{1, 0\}$ with the usual multiplication. Let $e_L = 1$ and $e_R = 0$. If $x = 1$, then $e_Lx = x$ and $x'x = e_L$ for $x' = 1$. If $x = 0$, then $xe_R = x$ and $xx' = e_R$ for $x' = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not mistaken. Here's a counterexample. Let $G$ and $H$ be
arbitrary groups, $A=G\cup H$. Define multiplication on the set $A$ by the
rule

$$
xy=
\left\{%
\begin{array}{ll}
    xy, & \hbox{if $x,y\in G$ or $x,y\in H$;} \\
    y, & \hbox{if $x\in G$ and $y\in H$;} \\
    x, & \hbox{if $x\in H$ and $y\in G$.} \\
\end{array}%
\right.
$$
Here $e_L=e_G$, $e_R=e_H$.

Comment: Nice non-commutative example (+1). Perhaps you have noted that for $x\in G$ and $y\in H$, we have $xy=yx=y$, that is, the product is always the element from $H$; this could save one branch in the definition, but perhaps it would be less clear.

Comment: Thank you @amrsa.
Maybe I should have commented on this point. But I wanted to make the example as concise as possible.

Comment: Yes, it's more concise than saying if one belongs to $G$ and another to $H$ then the product is the one from $H$. Although it may be a relevant observation, the definition as you stated is indeed more concise; it would actually be somewhat cumbersome to define it as I did above. I agree that it is better as it is.